# Can't translate the messages of the flag module

Tags: i18n-l10n, flags

I'm using Drupal 7.20 with Commerce. I installed the following modules:
 - internationalization module
 - translation helper
 - flag module

I have customized the text for my flag links to be 'add to my favorites' and 'remove from favorites'. I want to translate them, but they don't appear in the translate interface.

Does anyone have a clue?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[See this from the Flag module issue queue](https://drupal.org/node/669692#comment-2442918)

> Each string you enter as an administrator is available in the Translate Interface section, but you first have to switch to a different language, then view a page that contains that message (such as trying to flag/unflag a piece of content). Afterwards, the string will be flagged as needing a translation and you can find it in the Translate Interface section.

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work. Any clues if I am missing something?
I edited a flag, entered my custom text, went to my profile, changed my language, visited a page showing the flag text, checked in Translation Interface.

Answer (score 0):

You can translate everything if it's passed through `t()` function, for this purpose  you can use [String overrides](http://drupal.org/project/stringoverrides) module. If this values passed without `t()` function you need to find that `flag module` form function and override it in your module with [t()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/t/7).